# javascript .addclass for each date between start and end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a JQuery eventcalendar plugin from this [website](http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/).

My events have a start and end date and I have the following code which adds a green square on the calendar (one for the start date and one for the end date).

The bit I am struggling with is how to add a green square for each date between the start and end date.

```
eg start date - > 12-08-2012 
end date -> 15-08-12
```

Would highlight 12th 13th 14th and 15th

[image]

```
var eventDate = new Date(parseInt(event.startdate)),
eventYear = eventDate.getFullYear(),
eventMonth = eventDate.getMonth(),
eventDay = eventDate.getDate();

var eventDate1 = new Date(parseInt(event.enddate)),
eventYear1 = eventDate1.getFullYear(),
eventMonth1 = eventDate1.getMonth(),
eventDay1 = eventDate1.getDate();

// add mark in the dayList to the days with events
                    if (eventYear == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-year') && eventMonth == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-month')) {
                        flags.wrap.find('.currentMonth .eventsCalendar-daysList #dayList_' + eventDay).addClass('dayWithEvents');

                    }


if (eventYear1 == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-year') && eventMonth1 == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-month')) {
                        flags.wrap.find('.currentMonth .eventsCalendar-daysList #dayList_' + eventDay1).addClass('dayWithEvents');
                    }
```

Comment: Check the rendered html and CSS for the calender in the browser.. You need to override the styles associated with the wrapper

Comment: would i not just need a foreach date between start and end -------- flags.wrap.find('.currentMonth .eventsCalendar-daysList #dayList_' + datebetween).addClass('dayWithEvents');

Comment: In the class dayWithEvents you need to set the background-color: green !important ;  rule too override.. Are you doing this

Comment: I don't know what your getting at, the current setup works fine and  the background-color works fine. The bit I am struggling with is how to add a green square for each date between the start and end date.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made the same enhancement (still fine tuning it actually), and I used [datejs](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/) for the date matching. I've ported the calendar plugin to a github repo while I work on it, but this enhancement hasn't yet been pushed to it. If you're still interested in an answer, I can hurry up and finish it and provide the link - however it goes something like this:

```
var daysElement = $element.find('.currentMonth .eventsCalendar-daysList');
var dateToBeChecked = new Date(parseInt(event.startDate));
var endDate = new Date(parseInt(event.endDate));
while (dateToBeChecked.compareTo(endDate) <=0) {
    daysElement.find('#dayList_' + dateToBeChecked.getDate())
               .addClass('dayWithEvents');
    dateToBeChecked.addDays(1);
}
```

(Note that the "fine tuning" involves handling events that exist in 2 different calendar months, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar for the same script, whenever mouse-over the date that contains an end-date:

```
            // add mark in the dayList to the days with events
            if (eventYear == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-year') && eventMonth == flags.wrap.attr('data-current-month')) {
                flags.wrap.find('.currentMonth .eventsCalendar-daysList #dayList_' + parseInt(eventDay)).addClass('list-group-item-success');

            if (event.date_end) {
                 $('#dayList_' + parseInt(eventDay)).hover(
            function () {
                $('#dayList_' + parseInt(eventDay)).nextUntil('#dayList_' + parseInt(eventDayEnd)).andSelf().add('#dayList_' + parseInt(eventDayEnd)).addClass('list-group-item-danger');

                       },
            function () {
                $('#dayList_' + parseInt(eventDay)).nextUntil('#dayList_' + parseInt(eventDayEnd)).andSelf().add('#dayList_' + parseInt(eventDayEnd)).removeClass('list-group-item-danger');
                       }
            );

            }
```

Before the above will work, there are some modifications needed.
In the part where each data is generated:

```
$.each(data, function(key, event) {
```

i added some extra code: (first IF)

```
                    if (event.date_end) {
                    var eventDateTimeEnd = event.date_end.split(" "),
                        eventDateEnd = eventDateTimeEnd[0].split("-"),
                        eventTimeEnd = eventDateTimeEnd[1].split(":"),
                        eventYearEnd = eventDateEnd[0],
                        eventMonthEnd = parseInt(eventDateEnd[1]) - 1,
                        eventDayEnd = parseInt(eventDateEnd[2]),
                        //eventMonthToShow = eventMonth,
                        eventMonthToShowEnd = parseInt(eventMonthEnd) + 1,
                        eventHourEnd = eventTimeEnd[0],
                        eventMinuteEnd = eventTimeEnd[1],
                        eventSecondsEnd = eventTimeEnd[2],
                        eventDateEnd = new Date(eventYearEnd, eventMonthEnd, eventDayEnd, eventHourEnd, eventMinuteEnd, eventSecondsEnd);                           
                }
```

Second IF

```
                    if (event.date_end) {
                    var eventDateEnd = new Date(parseInt(event.date_end)),
                        eventYearEnd = eventDateEnd.getFullYear(),
                        eventMonthEnd = eventDateEnd.getMonth(),
                        eventDayEnd = eventDateEnd.getDate(),
                        eventMonthToShowEnd = eventMonthEnd + 1,
                        eventHourEnd = eventDateEnd.getHours(),
                        eventMinuteEnd = eventDateEnd.getMinutes();
                        }
```

As you can see i took the same code and just give it a new naming for each var, just added End to each var.

Then of course when push the event data you need to identify if the data contains an end date.
the formating you using will be different as yours, i made this script working with Bootstrap 3.10

```
if (event.date_end) {
                                    events.push('<li id="' + key + '" class="list-group-item '+event.type+'"><time datetime="'+eventDate+'"><em>' + eventStringDate + '</em><small>'+eventHour+":"+eventMinute+'</small></time>----TILL-----<time datetime="'+eventDateEnd+'"><em>' + eventStringDateEnd + '</em><small>'+eventHourEnd+":"+eventMinuteEnd+'</small></time>'+eventTitle+'<p class="eventDesc ' + eventDescClass + '">' + event.description + '</p></li>');
                                    }else{
                                    events.push('<li id="' + key + '" class="list-group-item '+event.type+'"><time datetime="'+eventDate+'"><em>' + eventStringDate + '</em><small>'+eventHour+":"+eventMinute+'</small></time>'+eventTitle+'<p class="eventDesc ' + eventDescClass + '">' + event.description + '</p></li>');
                                    }
```

In the generated Json i added a new field:

```
{ 
                        "date": "1394233485248", 
                        "type": "demo", 
                        "title": "Project B demo", 
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor.", 
                        "url": "http://www.event2.com/",
                        "date_end": "1402891200000" 
                        },
```

If anyone wants to help to retrieve the data from mysql/pdo database.... leave me a message.